# How to set Notification to be cleared by user swipe not via (Clear all)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using a notification with below flags, what I want is, that the user can clear this notification by making a swipe over it, yet, not to be cleared when user selects (Clear all).

P.S: I don't want it to be canceled when user click it, that's why I didn't use auto cancel.

```
Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: I would be somewhat surprised if what you want is possible. If the user can clear it individually, the user should be able to clear it as part of a clear-all request.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, I hoped it could be. BTW, What is the advantage of having FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT while we have FLAG_NO_CLEAR? Will it serve any purpose?

Comment: Ongoing notifications sort higher in the notification shade than do regular notifications. Also, FWIW, neither `NotificationCompat.Builder` nor `Notification.Builder` offer `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` as an option.